# Adjusting images based on sprites to 50% width from its parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

On this StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nnumuk?file=src%2Fstyle.css,src%2FApp.js

I have the following code:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="picture-tile">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/R2pDVJS/sprites.jpg"
            className="girlwithdog"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="picture-tile">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/R2pDVJS/sprites.jpg"
            className="girlwithbike"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="picture-tile">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/R2pDVJS/sprites.jpg"
            className="girlblowingbubbles"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="picture-tile">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/R2pDVJS/sprites.jpg"
            className="fatheranddaughter"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="picture-tile">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/R2pDVJS/sprites.jpg"
            className="fatheranddaughter2"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="picture-tile">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/R2pDVJS/sprites.jpg"
            className="couplewalkingdog"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="picture-tile">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/R2pDVJS/sprites.jpg"
            className="coupleonthebeach"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="picture-tile">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/R2pDVJS/sprites.jpg"
            className="coupleonscooter"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**style.css**

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
.picture-tile {
  display: inline-block;
}
.picture-tile > img {
  width: 483px;
  height: 483px;
  zoom: 0.5;
}
.picture-tile > .coupleonscooter {
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: 0 0;
}
.picture-tile > .coupleonthebeach {
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: -483px 0;
}
.picture-tile > .couplewalkingdog {
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: 0 -483px;
}
.picture-tile > .fatheranddaughter {
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: -483px -483px;
}
.picture-tile > .fatheranddaughter2 {
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: -966px 0;
}
.picture-tile > .girlwithbike {
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: -966px -483px;
}
.picture-tile > .girlwithdog {
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: 0 -966px;
}
.picture-tile > .girlblowingbubbles {
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: -483px -966px;
}
```

Then I get this output:
[image]

**But what I actually need is** that the images to be 50% width (and according height keeping aspect ratio) from the parent (yellow div). This needs be dynamically. I mean, if at some point the parent changes its div, then the images should be adjusted accordingly.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably easiest to work with percentages then. https://pagecrafter.com/responsive-background-image-sprites-css-tutorial/

Comment: Do you mean that there should be 2 photos in each row, and each photo should be 50% div?

Comment: @MahdiSamavi you are totally correct, 2 photos per row, and each photo half width of parent div.

Comment: @CBroe you mean percentages applied on that? if you want you can provide a StackBlitz fork. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can edit the styles written in the css file as follows:

```
.picture-tile {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50%;
}
.picture-tile > img {
   width: 100%;
   zoom: 0.75;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't work, please check this screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/TcWtGTr/image.png. Could you please try by yourself on the StackBlitz I provided above? Thanks!

Comment: I deleted the `height` and `zoom` if you notice.

Comment: Still not working. I'm getting this: https://i.ibb.co/V9vJtCz/image.png

Comment: Also delete zoom

Comment: when deleting the zoom, the sprite subimage is not showing up completely